# All array combinations with zero in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, zero

The following array is given

```
[10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 500, 500, 500, 1000, 1000, 1000, 5000]
```

I now want to loop to output all combinations of these numbers with 0. Each number can occur alone or with any other numbers in the array (the rest should be 0). The original position of the numbers should be maintained when they are included in a combination.

The numbers of the original array should remain in place and can only be replaced by a zero or not.

The size of the array always remains the same. So no zeros are added additionally. So it is not possible to insert zeros between the numbers of the original array increasing the length of the array.

And as the example input has three 10s, it is for example possible to have the first 10, then 0, and then 10 again.

There is no requirement for the order in which the combinations are produced.

I just want to clarify my idea with the following example.

```
[10,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10, 10,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0,  10,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0,  10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10, 10, 10, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0,   0,  0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0,   0, 10, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0,   10, 10, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 10, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 10, 10, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 10, 10, 50, 50, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 10, 50, 50, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What would be the best way to proceed here?

Comment: Please post the code you have, along with specific questions related to that. SO is not a homework solving service.

Comment: @Philipp2706 Can you read Python code (without specific constructions)?

Comment: *"I don't think that the order in the following example is correct."*: why not? This requirement about ascending order is quite vague, for instance, in `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]` the non-zero numbers appear in ascending order (there is only one non-zero). Yet, it is not clear whether this is an acceptable combination. Is the requirement that when a non-zero value is included, it should be at its *original* position?

Comment: @marthursson I don't want a ready-made solution but the description of an approach would help me. I have already tried some approaches but have discarded all again. 
But I will post one of my approaches if it is reasonably promising :)

Comment: @MBo I could try to translate the code into Java

Comment: @Philipp2706 You need to put items on the same positions? And no zeros between ([10,10,0,50,...])?

Comment: @trincot Sorry, I did not express myself clearly. I have changed my post.
I mean that the ascending order in the original array should be maintained, so that each digit should remain at its position.

Comment: Is there any requirement for the order in which the combinations are produced? Do you realise that there are over 60 000 of such combinations? Is it expected to have such a huge output?

Comment: @MBo The numbers of the original array should remain in place and can only be replaced by a zero or not.
The size of the array always remains the same. So no zeros are added additionally.

Comment: I think you mean *numbers*, not *digits*.

Comment: @trincot No, there is no order to this. I have already thought that there are many possibilities. But that is ok :D

Comment: I meant  - is it possible to put 10, then 0, then 10 again?  - all your examples have contiguous sequence of non-zero values

Comment: @MBo Yes that is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task really translates to producing binary numbers of 15 binary digits, where a 0 means "produce a 0" and a 1 means "copy the number from the input at this position".

It is then clear that there are 2<sup>15</sup> combinations as that is the number of numbers you can produce using 15 bits.

So an implementation in JavaScript could be:

```js
let input = [10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 500, 500, 500, 1000, 1000, 1000, 5000];

let quit = 20; // For demo purpose, let's stop after 20 outputs...
let count = Math.pow(2, 15); // Total number of combinations
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) { // For each combination
    let combi = []; // Create new empty array
    for (let bit = 0, bits = i; bit < 15; bit++, bits >>= 1) {
        // Depending on bit, either append 0 or the input to the array
        combi.push(bits & 1 ? input[bit] : 0); 
    }
    console.log(...combi); // Output all values in the array
    if (quit-- < 0) break; // For this demo only
}
```